# Git showing different results when using dif and diff-index

Tags: git, diff

I am trying to see if some local files are in sync with my git repo and for this I am using the following command

```
git diff-index --name-only HEAD --;
```

The problem is that this is showing files that are marked as changed when they aren't

I get no file differences when using the following command

```
git diff --name-only HEAD --;
```

Why am I getting different results?!

Thank you!

Comment: What kind of differences are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

if you are checking the state of the files use `git status` and it'll show you what is not synced with your repo

on each file of the not synced use `git diff file_name` and you will see the difference between the repo state and the current state